# Magento. Как добавить в конец url onepage/success параметр last order id

Tags: url, magento, observer

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как обсервером в конец url страницы success добавить параметр с айдишником последнего заказа, то есть чтобы вместо

> .../checkout/onepage/success/

было

> .../checkout/onepage/success/order_id=10000000001

код observer'a в config.xml

```
        ....
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <dk_images>
                        <!-- <type>singleton</type> -->
                        <class>DK_Images_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                    </dk_images>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>    
        </events>
    </global>
```

контроллер

```
<?php
class DK_Images_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract 
{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('checkout/onepage', $this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {  
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();//trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);


        if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($parts[5] == 'onepage' && $parts[6] == 'success') {


            $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                   ->getLastRealOrderId();

            $request->setModuleName('checkout')
                    ->setControllerName('onepage')
                    ->setActionName('success')
                    ->setParam('id', $lastOrderId);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Но данный код, к сожалению, не работает. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: таак зачем вам это и последнего заказа вообще, или пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вопрос зачем тут кстати, может если будет понятно зачем то будут новые варианты решения задачи?

Как вариант, создаем шаблон в который будет принимать Ид заказа и [пушить](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) его как параметр УРЛ через js, ну и собсвенно обзервером просто добавляем наш шаблон в before_body_end или что-то типа того, где он отработает и изменит УРЛ.

Это если нужно только урл поменять, а не чтобы именно на него попадал пользователь, для этого проще переписать контроллер.